Difference in regular expressions in Find_and_Replace and RegExp
I need to find and replace text consisting of the characters: * one character, - one character, one or more digits, - one character, one or more letters, _ one or more characters.
In RegExp I successfully use the pattern "*{1}-{1}\d{1,}-{1}[A-Z]{1,}_{1,}" to find the first match (this is necessary in my code), then I try to apply the same pattern in the Find_and_Replace method and nothing changes.
It's code work:
    Set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.IgnoreCase = False
    regEx.MultiLine = True
    regEx.Global = False
    regEx.Pattern = "\*{1}\-{1}\d{1,}\-{1}[A-Z]{1,}\_{1,}"

    If regEx.Test(Rng) Then
        Set Matches = regEx.Execute(Rng)
        MsgBox Matches(0).FirstIndex + 1
    Else
        MsgBox 0
    End If

This code don't work:
    With Rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\*{1}\-{1}\d{1,}\-{1}[A-Z]{1,}\_{1,}"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = True
        With .Replacement
            .ClearFormatting
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Underline = True
            
            .Text = "Bla-bla-bla"

        End With
        
        .Execute
    
        If .Found = True Then
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        End If
   end with


Word Find is not egex and in general you should not expect a wildcard Find to behave the same way as a RexExp find. Your pattern found (e.g.) *-dd-ABC__ here. Perhaps you need ";" instead of "," in the Word Find but not the RexExp Find, , or are looking for something else, or have very long sequences of "d" or [A-Z] that break a Word limit?

.Text = "\*-[0-9]@-[A-Z]@_{1,}"

or, if you're not using English-language regional settings:
.Text = "\*-[0-9]@-[A-Z]@_{1;}"

The above will find content like:
*-1-A_
*-12-A_
*-1-AB_
*-12-AB__
and so on.

Doesn't work.
My solution: For RegExp: "*{1}-{1}\d{1,}-{1}[A-Z]{1,}_{1,}"
For Find and Replace method: "*{1}-{1}[0-9]{1,}-{1}[A-Z]{1,}_{1,}"
macropod, what is the reason for this behavior? Local ms-word settings?

See revised answer
